# Concatenating multiple barplots in seaborn

Tags: python-3.x, bar-chart, seaborn

My data-frame contains the following column headers: subject, Group, MASQ_GDA, MASQ_AA, MASQ_GDD, MASQ_AD

I was successfully able to plot one of them using a bar plot with the following specifications:

```
bar_plot = sns.barplot(x="Group", y='MASQ_GDA', units="subject", ci = 68, hue="Group", data=demo_masq)
```

However, I am attempting to create several of such bar plot side by side. Might anyone know how I can accomplish this, for each plot to contain the remaining 3 variables (MASQ_AA, MASQ_GDD, MASQ_AD). Here is an example of what I am trying to achieve.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look in [the documentation for `sns.barplot()`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.barplot.html), you will see that the function accepts a parameter `ax=` allowing you to tell seaborn which Axes object to use to plot the result

> ax : matplotlib Axes, optional
>
> Axes object to draw the plot onto, otherwise uses the current Axes.

Therefore, the simple way to obtain the desired output is to create the Axes beforehand, and then calling `sns.barplot()` with the corresponding `ax` parameter

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(1,4)  # create 4 subplots on 1 row
for ax,col in zip(axs,["MASQ_GDA", "MASQ_AA", "MASQ_GDD", "MASQ_AD"]):
    sns.barplot(x="Group", y=col, units="subject", ci = 68, hue="Group", data=demo_masq, ax=ax)  # <- notice ax= argument
```

Another option, and maybe an option that is more in line with the philosophy of seaborn is to use [a FacetGrid](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.FacetGrid.html#seaborn.FacetGrid). This would allow you to automatically create the required number of subplots depending on the number of categories in your dataset. However, it requires to reshape your dataframe so that the content of your `MASQ_*` columns are on a single column, with a new column showing what category each value corresponds to.

Comment: Thank you for the information. The first option works, however, it results in y-axis labels which appear superimposed on the bar graphs, instead of just one. Not pretty. Additionally, the legends are incorrectly superimposed and the order (hue) is not kept consistent. Do you know of a way to correct those? If not, I will go for reshaping the dataset as you suggested. Thanks again.

Comment: Either you have to play with the options to `barplot()` for each of the plot to get the desired output, or you have to use a FacetGrid (or the new [`sns.catplot()`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.catplot.html#seaborn.catplot) in v.0.9.0) , but you'll have to transform your data